# what data structure is this? - What language?

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary

```
[35 => "Rocko", 36 => "Modern", 37 => "Life"]
```

I am not sure what that is or what language that is.

It looks like:

```
[{
"35":"Rocko",
"36":"Modern",
"37":"Life"
}]
```

for python but I am pretty sure that is not python. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks like it could be PHP.  Consider the following short PHP script:

```php
$array = [35 => "Rocko", 36 => "Modern", 37 => "Life"];
print_r($array);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [35] => Rocko
    [36] => Modern
    [37] => Life
)
```

Comment: I think you are right: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php